# Can't upload app to iTunes connect Xcode 9

Tags: app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, xcode9

I had checked my provision profile and certificate. It was no problem to upload app in Xcode 7, but after update to Xcode 9, I receive error in Xcode

`Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision`

[image]

From application uploader I have error, too. Spent a lot of time to fix this problem, but has no idea for this time.

Comment: Are you trying to upload an .ipa?  If so, change it to .zip and then unzip the archive.  Inside the folder, you should see a file embedded.mobileprovision.  If not, your code signing settings are wrong.  You will need to chow your project code signing settings.  Other people are submitting apps with Xcode 9, so I doubt there is a global problem with Xcode 9 - it seems to be something specific to you.

Answer (score 0):

The IPA structure for any IPA is as follows. Make sure to rename the IPA to .zip and extract, then you will have to Ctrl+Click and say show package contents to see the inside App.

*Structure :*

```
Payload
    MyApp.app
      -- _CodeSignature
      -- Plugins (optional if you have extension like Siri, widget)
      -- Watch (optional if you have extensions for watch)
      -- archived-content....xccent
      **-- embedded-provisionign.profile**
      -- Info.plist
```

Now check this profile if its double clicked and installed properly in your Xcode and found, if not the profile cert and p12, and profile file have issued from the generation time. Solve this and try to compile new IPA.

It should solve your purpose. Note If you are using a developer account, go to its dev portal member centre and see if the profile and AppId are valid as per one in the code. You can check the extracted above Plist for the CFBundleIdentifier value and check if its relevant dev account portal profile is Active and not Invalid due to any cause for that APP ID associated with the profile.